# Como obter imagem do perfil via autenticação utilizando API facebook php

Tags: php, facebook, url, imagem

Gostaria de saber como faço para copiar uma imagem de um link sem extensão, ou seja, já usei diversos métodos que funcionam para imagens com extensão, mas sem extensão não consegui ainda, onde vou utilizar para copiar a imagem do perfil do Facebook quando as pessoas acessarem meu sistema.

[Exemplo da url da imagem](https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xft1/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/11096518_845923738813093_6295484000724529473_n.jpg?oh=dcb454d6a58b38a9b5c53c6a77fa77fc&oe=567D1360&__gda__=1449651572_a7afd3bd8fc0ee5da218487c49a7d18c)

Estou utilizando essa função em javascript:

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name,email,picture,gender,age_range,link,locale'}, function(response) {});
```

Onde pego na resposta a url descrita acima.
Sei que tem extenção a imagem, mas colocando somente a extensão para acessar a imagem, ele apresenta o seguinte erro:

> "An error occurred while processing your request.
>   Reference #50.2f2cfea5.1441047871.5277eeef"

Comment: Já usou a API do Facebook para isso ?

Comment: Esse url tem a extensão da imagem: **jpg** ...//fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xft1/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/11096518_845923738813093_6295484000724529473_n.**jpg**?oh=dcb454d6a58b38a9b5c53c6a77fa77fc&oe=567D1360&__gda__=1449651572_a7afd3bd8fc0ee5da218487c49a7d18c

Comment: Faça isso e diga o resultado: `...function(response) {
    console.log(response);
}`

Answer (score 5):

O melhor caminho, nesse caso, é criar uma autenticação através da API do Facebook em PHP. Assim, você conseguirá obter informações do perfil do usuário e repassa-las para o seu site. A sua pergunta deveria ser editada.

Com isso você obteria a foto do perfil ATUAL do usuário simplesmente com isso(e muitas outras configurações):

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $_SESSION['USERNAME']; ?>/picture">
```

[Fonte](http://www.krizna.com/general/login-with-facebook-using-php/)

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins?locale=pt_BR